# JUnit adding extra tests to Test Case

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm using Eclipse I've got some JUnit 4 test cases defined. Some of the classes have changed (only slightly at the moment) and I was wondering if there's any way to open up the GUI where I can select the methods I want to create test stubs for again to update the existing test cases.

I know I could add them manually and I could also create a new Test Case with a different file name and then copy and paste them, but is there any way to update the Test Case from the Class in a smoother way?

Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a plugin called [MoreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/). If you are on a method, you can press `Ctrl+U` to generate a test method in the test class. You can then press `Ctrl+J` to jump to the test method and implement it. It also puts an icon in the editor gutter next to methods which have test cases.

Comment: Great, thanks (+1). I started writing something like that myself years ago, but abandoned it.